# What's the recommended syntax for an image with a link?

Tags: support, faq, markdown, hyperlinks, images

What's the recommended syntax for an image with a hyperlink? I tried doing it
with the markdown toolbar buttons and the image and link buttons conflict
with each other, so I had to resort to HTML.

For example, to do this:

[image]

These work properly:

```
<a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/44330/jason-s">![alt text][1]</a>
[1]: https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dd5a7ef1476fb01998a215b1642dfd07

<a href="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/44330/jason-s">
   <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dd5a7ef1476fb01998a215b1642dfd07">
</a>

[<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dd5a7ef1476fb01998a215b1642dfd07">][2]
[2]: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/44330/jason-s
```

This does not:

```
<a href='https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/44330/jason-s'>![alt text][1]</a>
```

(single quotes not allowed?)

Is there a way to do the same thing in Markdown without having to resort to HTML?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

It is possible to use Markdown for both the image and the link.
You have to do it manually because the the toolbar's default behavior
is to make the clickable image point to the URL of the image itself.

---

#### Reference-style

```
[![alt text][image]][hyperlink]

[hyperlink]: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/44330/jason-s
[image]:
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dd5a7ef1476fb01998a215b1642dfd07
(tooltip)
  – or –
[image]:
https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/dd5a7ef1476fb01998a215b1642dfd07
"tooltip"
```

##### Example

[image]

##### Default behavior, reference-style

Since [July 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261182) the insert
image feature (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>) of the toolbar of the
Stack Exchange Markdown editor by default adds a clickable link to the
image itself.
<sup>1</sup>

It uses the following syntax:

```
[![enter image description here][number]][number]
```

where `number` is an automatically generated number.

##### Default example, reference-style

```
[![Jason's avatar][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png
"Tooltip for Jason's avatar"
```

[image: Jason's avatar]

To change the link to something else, simply change the second
`[number]` with `(*your URL here*)` (in parentheses) or use the
reference style syntax above.

---

#### Inline-style

```
[![alt text](image "tooltip")](hyperlink)
  for example:
[![invisible description of images, read aloud to blind users
](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png
"Let's check Jason S' profile page (inline-style)")
](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/44330/jason-s)
```

[image: invisible description of images, read aloud to blind users]

##### Default behavior, inline-style

You can get the default behavior *without using the `[number]`
construct*.

```
[![A click on the image links to its own URL.](
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png
"A click on the image links to its own URL (inline-style).")
](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X14m7.png)
```

[image: A click on the image links to its own URL.]

The observant reader will notice that to achieve the *inline-style
default behavior*, the URL to the image must be supplied ***twice***.
The first link is there to ***display*** the image, the second link
***makes the image clickable***.

---

#### References:

- [From 2015, the image uploader automatically wraps images in a link
  to themselves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261182)
- [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)
  | Editing and Formatting
- [Extra square brackets and numbers when using automated link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261863)
- [Why does the images index on Stack Overflow appear twice?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307069)

---

<sup>1</sup> The previous default behavior was to just display the
image - without any link at all. ~ * ~ Even the new default behavior
does not add any tooltip for you. – If you want a tooltip, you have to
add it yourself.

Comment: In other words, whatever the syntax for the image, treat that whole syntax as the text to link. So the ugly syntax also works: `[![alt text](image link)](web link)`

Comment: Excellent! It makes sense but I never got that far in because once I start typing it I think to myself, this can't possibly be right, it's too ugly. but it aint... you ugly! ;)

Comment: This works in general for Markdown, not only for StackOverflow, it seems!

Comment: +1 for the (hover text) tip.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR This doesn't work for chat. Is there a way to do this in chat?

Comment: @mbomb007 I don't know, sorry.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR this should be another answer since it's a simpler different form

Answer (score 4):

For numerically indexed URLs, just **make a new numbered URL**.

For example, when you insert an image with the fancy editor, it starts off linking to itself. In HTML terms, the `a.href` link URL is the same as `img.src` image URL.

```
[![alt text][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPW28.png
```

Just add a new URL for the link:

```
[![alt text][1]][2]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPW28.png
[2]: https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/moon/light.html?month=3&day=20&year=2040&hour=19&min=00&sec=0&n=64&ntxt=Chicago&earth=0
```

The result:

[image]

So `(http://example.com)` can be replaced with `[42]` ... `[42]: http://example.com`

Comment: it is better to edit the original answer, which is Community Wiki, then to append one. For clarity.