# Creating an image link in Markdown format

Tags: support, hyperlinks, markdown, images

How can I create an image link using the Markdown format? I want an output like `<a href="" rel="some text"><img src="/path/to/file" alt="" /></a>`. I can't seem to find the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: `![](/path/to/file)`

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/recommended-syntax-for-an-image-with-a-link

Comment: May be this should be added to the FAQ and/or the editing help?

Comment: @Henke those links should be removed altogether – moderators and gold tag badge holders can do so, by reopening and closing the question again.

Answer (score 262):

There does not appear to be a single markdown construct that will do what you want, however both of the following pieces of markdown work (as least on SO):

```
[<img src="http://www.google.com.au/images/nav_logo7.png">](http://google.com.au/)

[![Foo](http://www.google.com.au/images/nav_logo7.png)](http://google.com.au/)
```

I agree it would be a handy thing to have (along with markdown markup for width, height, floating left or right and adding a caption).

EDIT: I don't think there is any markdown available for the `rel` attribute of links.

```
<a href="http://google.com.au/" rel="some text">![Foo](http://www.google.com.au/images/nav_logo7.png)</a>
```

The above looks like your best case, although by this stage you almost might as well just use HTML for the image as well and be done with it.

Comment: At least in MarkDown Extra the following, more readable approach, will also work:

###  [SmartyPants][] and other goodies
    
[![SmartyPantsImg][]][SmartyPants]

[SmartyPants]: http://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/`
[SmartyPantsImg]: http://daringfireball.net/graphics/smartypants_title.gif`

Comment: This is working for me.
Markdown for image and link:
[![Day calendar](http://i.imgur.com/uqmd4li.jpg "Day calendar")][ss1]
Link reference:
[ss1]: http://imgur.com/uqmd4li

See it in action: https://github.com/Rundiz/thai-calendar

Comment: The second example works on GitHub.

Comment: The first example works on thingiverse.

Comment: This works in wordpress.com markdown enabled posts as well. Here's an example, https://atiqcs.wordpress.com/2018/07/05/ssl-binding-azure-paas-windows-server/

Comment: There is an extra `]` before `</a>` in the third example

Comment: @grrigore Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: the 2nd one works fine on GitHub markup too, any idea how to open the link in a new tab? (aka target="_blank") when using that syntax (the non-html one)