# Is it appropriate to emplace a "Donate" button on one's SO profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, donation

Is it appropriate to [ask for donations on ones profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420197/ionic-bizu)? To me, it seems to be somewhat at odds with the goal of SO.

Comment: Apart from all that, that is an amazing contact form!

Comment: If I vote this question up, does that mean I feel that the "Donate" button is or is not appropriate?

Comment: Yeah it is! :-D

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: It means that you agree it should be discussed.

Comment: I'd like to say that people can put whatever they want in their profiles, but this does seem a bit... excessive.

Comment: It's perfectly okay. Let me look for the dupe...

Comment: I think it's a little bit crass, but then I'm British, so I'm embarrassed talking about money :-)

Comment: @thecoshman      

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. I believe it is.

There are very few places where you are allowed to advertise yourself or the product.

If people want to add donate buttons so people can donate them money if they helped them I think it's completely appropriate. It's not just that user, for example [Gordon for example has an Amazon wishlist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208809/gordon) and that is appropriate as well.

That said:

- The issue of allowing payment for quicker answers was discussed and there is a consensus that it's a bad idea.
- You shouldn't ask for money on questions. Never, nor condition an answer on payment, or suggest it. That's not what this community is for.

Also, this is very similar to how it is allowed to promote your personal website, interests, favorite projects, tools and contracting & consulting services on your profile.

Comment: Right, well, up a donate link goes, then!!

Comment: Actually I can't quite figure out how he did it, with the Markdown options available.. hmm

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Isn't it just a link and image? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38917/210016

Comment: PayPal's button generator gives me a form (which won't work), but I'll try that