# Eeeek! Why is this image disappearing while embedding it?

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, images

I'm trying to make the image in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/325891/what-are-the-internal-workings-of-google-voice/325926#325926) clickable.

So I follow [these instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/whats-the-recommended-syntax-for-an-image-with-a-link/2191#2191):

```
[![alt text][1]][2]
```

but .... **Eeeek! The image disappears!** This also doesn't work:

```
[![alt text][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTc6L.jpg)
```

What's going on? This used to work before, but it seems broken, starting today. Others are having the [same problem](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2164/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011/3203#3203). Curiously, if you try to edit the [instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/whats-the-recommended-syntax-for-an-image-with-a-link/2191#2191), the image disappears, too.

<sub>Chrome Dev on OS X, doesn't work on other systems either.</sub>

Comment: Nuts. I was just trying this and submitted an edit when I realized I don't have edit privileges on SU... Needless to say, it didn't work for me, either. Feel free to reject that edit.

Comment: Editing the linked *question* with the instructions works fine for me. But editing [the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/whats-the-recommended-syntax-for-an-image-with-a-link/2191#2191) indeed gets me an empty `<a href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/44330/jason-s"></a>`in the preview. (And probably the same when actually saving it?)

Comment: Seems adding the link to Thunderbird causes the image to vanish http://i.imgur.com/NdbJp.png http://i.imgur.com/ZeUDa.png

Comment: Workaround until this is fixed: Use HTML tags.

Comment: <a href="http://i.stack.imgur.com/hTc6L.jpg"><img src="http://i.stack.imgur.com/hTc6Lm.jpg" /></a>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We recently made a change to prevent link-within-a-link creation. That change was a little too eager, so it also broke image-within-a-link.

Fixed now.