# How do I make my scaled image link to the full size image?

Tags: support, markdown, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the recommended syntax for an image with a link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/whats-the-recommended-syntax-for-an-image-with-a-link)

I understand why the image is scaled, but how do I link to the full size version?  Every time I highlight it and click to add a link, it removes the image and leaves the description without a link around it.

Comment: Have you tried throwing a hyperlink to the full image on top of the image blocks?

Comment: @Mysticial What are "image blocks"?  Can you give me an example of what that would look like in text?  Thanks

Comment: In the markdown, there should be some blocks that are where the image should go. Although I've never tried it myself, I might be possible to just throw a hyperlink over the whole thing.

Comment: @Mysticial Yeah that's what I've tried.  When I do that (by clicking the link button) it removes the link and leaves the description as plain text.

Comment: Ah... then I dunno... :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After uploading your image, the editor auto-inserts the Markdown code for displaying the image:

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

To link to the full-sized image, wrap a `[...][1]` around the above code:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Adjust the link number accordingly.