# Extra square brackets and numbers when using automated link or add picture feature in questions and answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, answers, images

I have recently noticed that when using the automated feature to add links, or to add images:

[image]

That instead of getting:

```
![enter image description here][2]
```

You get:

```
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
```

And I often find the same with links too. This appears to be a bug as there is no functionality for these extra bits and they didn't used to appear.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151793/support-showing-image-in-original-size-in-overlay/261182#261182

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [has been added recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261182) to images, so they can be easily opened in another browser tab/window.

This does not happen with links - don't know where you encountered that.

Comment: Here I thought it was a bug and I was removing the extra characters every time. Good to know.

Comment: Looks like it confuses many users, especially veteran, who end up removing this and thinking it's a bug. Maybe add a checkbox in the uploader (e.g. above "Add Picture" button) labeled something like "Auto link to full size image"? (ticked by default)

Comment: [And yet another innocent victim](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272788/markdown-for-images?lq=1). :)