# Markdown editing help should mention something about the extra brackets which appears when posting images

Tags: feature-request, markdown, images, editing-help

There [has been a small change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261182/293416) implemented when posting images. There will be some extra brackets.

Currently, the markdown editing page (eg: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images)) does not mention anything about this feature.

Shouldn't some information on this be added into the markdown editing page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Markdown for images - when will the help pages be updated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360423/markdown-for-images-when-will-the-help-pages-be-updated)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the recommended syntax for an image with a link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/whats-the-recommended-syntax-for-an-image-with-a-link)