# Markdown for images

Tags: discussion, markdown, images, editor

Just curious here.

According to the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), you can use this markdown for images:

```
![sample image](http://example.com/img.jpg)
```

And if we want, we can also use the "reference" format for images

```
![sample image][1]

 [1]: http://example.com/img.jpg
```

So far, so good. However, the editor interface uses another format, which I'm not sure I understand the syntax of.

```
[![sample image][1]][1]

 [1]: http://example.com/img.jpg
```

with the extra brackets and the duplicated `[1]`. How does that work? If I remove the inner `[1]`, I get one visible `[` in front of the image.

Like I said, just curious. I can't find this format documented anywhere. And I don't understand why there are so many different ways to insert images. Do some of those formats have features the others don't have?

Comment: This is quite a recent change, meant to link to the full image, since many times users post large images which get resized in the post.

Comment: The markdown help still needs updating. There is a question about this as well. [Markdown editing help should mention something about the extra brackets which appears when posting images](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267204)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and second options you mention are equivalent. They both insert an image by providing the URL to that image.

The third option also adds a link: it combines the link markdown `[link text][ref]` with the image markdown `![alt text][ref]` to form `[![alt text][image ref]][link]`.

Using this, you get a linked image, which is useful because it lets you see the larger version if one is available (the display may downsize a large image).

Comment: Ah... Of course I knew that images here are usually links to their full versions. And now you mention it, it's so clear that this syntax is simply an image nested in a link. Thanks for rubbing my nose in it!