# Markdown when inserting images strange

Tags: support, markdown, images

I have inserted three images in my superuser question - see [revision 2](https://superuser.com/revisions/1172545/2).

The links were all inserted as `[![enter image description here][1]][1]`. It seems to work fine, but I would expect simpler syntax `![enter image description here][1]` and when I have edited it to such syntax, it still seems to work.

I was inserting them by clicking to Image button and copying an image from clipboard.

To keep the question self contained, I am adding a small image into this question as well.

[image]

Comment: It _used to_ work exactly as you're expecting. This [was changed back in July, 2015](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261182/21960) to the current behavior.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the recommended syntax for an image with a link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2133/whats-the-recommended-syntax-for-an-image-with-a-link)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the intended markdown. What you're *actually* seeing is an image inside of a link. This allows us to click on the link, to open it.

You can see this in the example below. In the example, we can replace "this is a link" in the link markdown with the image markdown, and we are left with the image markdown as per what you see when you upload images into your questions.

`[this is a link][1]`
`![this is an image][1]`
`[![this is an image inside a link][1]][1]`

You can also extend this functionality by replacing the *outer* number to point to a *specific* link. While rare, I find this can *sometimes* be useful. Note that in such cases, I find it important to include a "rollover" description to further alert the user to the altered link.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is done so the image is clickable and can be directly opened.