# Do we really need linked images?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, images, uploader

I had posted a question, *[What is the correct way to insert images to Stack Exchange posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361357)*, where I asked what the correct way to insert images into Stack Exchange posts was. I included the default method:

```
[![example image][1]][1]

  [1]: image-url
```

I also mentioned a way I found out to be working:

```
![example image][1]

  [1]: image-url
```

I got an answer, a nice one, and it gave yet another method:

```
[![example image](image-url)](image-url)
```

I am now confused why two out of these three methods provide linked images? Why do we need them?

I mean, yes it helps viewers to open the images in full screen to better understand the details, but that can easily be done with a normal image as well [right click => open image in new tab (keep pressing => open image in new tab for touch screens)].

So the basic question is "do we really need linked images?". They can cause a bit of fuss on accidental clicks (which are particularly common on touch screens). And if they aren't really needed, then why are they a part of the uploader's default setup?

Comment: you can just right click and open in new tab

Comment: "*I mean, yes it helps viewers to open the images in full screen to better understand the details, but that can easily be done with a normal image as well*" any reason you want to make it *harder* to open the image for full view? Note that if you insert an image with the button it automatically embeds it and makes it a link, so changing that means *you* are doing more work as well. My counter question is: do you really need it to *not* be a link?

Comment: @mindstormsboi exactly. That's what I have mentioned.

Comment: @VLAZ Adding links just increases the total markup. Obviously it's just fine with links, but I just want to know why do we really need to call them the "default"..

Comment: "*Adding links just increases the total markup.*" and?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Linked images are not *required*; you won't get banned if you never use them. You don't even get more downvotes (or less upvotes) for not using linked images. I'll admit that I sometimes type `![]()` and then paste an image URL from another Stack Exchange post into it myself.

That said, I mentioned the reason to prefer linked images already in the post you linked to

> The advantage of using a link is mainly when it comes to large images. They can be clicked and zoomed (which is especially useful for mobile users). Also, it's possible to use a smaller version of the image in the post itself, so that it takes less time to load and doesn't take too much space.

and [@ColleenV's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361357/what-is-the-correct-way-to-insert-images-to-stack-posts#comment1205942_361359) provides some concrete examples:

> Here is an example of [an answer of mine](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/68913/9161) where I wanted small thumbnails in the answer, but I wanted people to be able to see a larger version of the image by clicking. Also, the image link can go anywhere, not just to another image - there's an example of that in [this post I wrote on ELL's meta about working with images](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3318/9161).

Do these reasons always apply? Definitely not. Why does the uploader produce linked images then? Because the cases where it *hurts* to have a linked image are few and far between (the only two reasons I can think of are "I don't like it" and "My post ends up being longer than 30,000 characters"), while the cases where it is *beneficial* occur (much) more often.

Comment: "*My post ends up being longer than 30,000 characters*" I think the 5 extra characters per image to make it a link are hardly **the** thing that will push a post over 30k characters. It'd be a rather extreme edge case. Most likely a sentence or two can be cut out that will give enough another 10-20 links for images.

Comment: Completely agree, there's a reason why I listed it even after "I don't like it" ...